# How to Save User Input (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I have a dropdown menu which is populated through the combination of two different object values `contact.firstName` and `contact.lastName`. How can I submit these two values separately on `POST` so I can query them at a later time? This issue arose because I need to handle when a first name or last name is more than one word.

views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj.contact = request.POST.get('select_contacts')
```

template.html

```
<div class="select">
    <select name="select_contacts" id="select_contacts" required>
        <option value="">Contact</option>
        % for contact in contacts %}
        <option value="{{ contact.firstName }} {{ contact.lastName }}" name="selected_contact" id="selected_contact">{{ contact.firstName }}  {{ contact.lastName }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent issues with referencing objects by concatenated char fields, you should instead use the contact id to reference the contact object:

```
<option value="{{ contact.id }}" name="selected_contact" id="selected_contact">{{ contact.firstName }}  {{ contact.lastName }}</option>
```

Then set the `contact_id` on the related model so it properly references the contact object:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj.contact_id = request.POST.get('selected_contact')
```

This assumes that `obj.contact` is a ForeignKey of a model named `Contact`, e.g.:

```
class Whatever(models.Model):
    contact = ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This relationship will ensure you are always preserving referential integrity, and will prevent issues like the one you encountered, as well as other issues, e.g. when two contacts have the same name.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Originally, I was going to use a flat database but now I will need referential integrity. So I am especially interested in implementing your solution. However, when I `request.POST.get()` of the select object, the value returned is that of the actual option selected and not `value="my_id"`; and when I reference the actual option, the value is null. Why is it not returning the value of the particular element?

Comment: @garmars I see what you're saying.  The problem there is that you can't retrieve an unselected option's value from a <select> component on the server side.  When the form is submitted, it will only post the selected option(s).  What is the reason for wanting to retrieve a value other than the selected option?